# How to get the old larger SDK on BizTalk 2020?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I checked to install the BizTalk SDK during my setup, and this is what I now see in the SDK folder:

[image]

I don't see the old SDK that came in some prior releases ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/samples-in-the-sdk)).  I searched my entire disk for *.odx looking for SDK and didn't find any (other than the VS orchestration Template).

I did a Google search for download BizTalk 2020 SDK and nothing of interest showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BizTalk 2020 [Deprecated & Removed List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020#deprecated--removed-list)

> Samples:      Removed from BizTalk Server installation.

So they just aren't available I would say.

Comment: That's bizarre; seems like they would just bring them in to 2020 and compile them and continue to include them.